# Website Transcoder (similar to google weblight - happy to self host)

Tags: html, php, web-server

Up until about 2 months ago I was regularly using google weblight. This was a very useful transcoder, for providing simplified html pages without https to legacy devices. However, as of recently this service no longer seems to work.

So my quesition is whether a similar tool exist. I am happy to host this myself, but I do need a page simplification proxy that is able to remove ssl and tsl encyryption. I am especially in need of this when accessing the internet over slow 2g connections in rural areas.

Thanks in advance, sorry that I dont have any more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to translate.google.com and paste your URL in the translate box then click the link in the translated box and it will translate it.

You can also get the google translate extension for chrome here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb

Comment: I don't think that "transcoding" is the same as "translating".